# How to make a merge join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one main table and two other tables.

dict_country: id 
user_country_ticket: country_id, ticket
country_ticket: country_id, ticket

This select:

```
select self.id, ct.ticket, uct.ticket
from country self
left join user_country_ticket uct on uct.country_id = self.id
left join country_ticket ct on ct.country_id = self.id
```

returns
id, ticket, ticket
66, 3, 2

I want to join only one ticket.
From user_country_ticket if there is ticket in that table,
otherwise ticket should be joined from country_ticket,
otherwise ticket should be null

so select must return
id, ticket
66, 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use coalesce:

```
select self.id, coalesce(ct.ticket,uct.ticket)
from country self
left join user_country_ticket uct on uct.country_id = self.id
left join country_ticket ct on ct.country_id = self.id
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! Only it is coalesce function in postgresql.

Comment: i see. did not see that though but you understand the logic. cheers.